# react native, drawable/launch_screen.png not found

Tags: android, react-native

When I run my android project I get the error below, launch_screen.png exists in the relevant folder.

How can I fix the error?

> \android\app\src\main\res\layout\launch_screen.xml:5: AAPT: error: resource drawable/launch_screen.png (aka com.rg.tc:drawable/launch_screen.png) not found.
>
> React Native Environment Info:
> System:
> OS: Windows 10
> CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
> Memory: 1.31 GB / 7.86 GB
> Binaries:
> npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
> IDEs:
> Android Studio: Version 3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312
> "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0"

[image]

Comment: Can you put some code of your app

Comment: you should be looking at `main/res/layout/drawable` instead of `main/res/drawable`.

Comment: you might have a duplicate file or just have accidentally deleted the file while trying to fix it, whenever i get that error. i run rm -rf node modules then npm i, find the duplicate file, delete it, then run the app again